# Given a wide single value sequence break it down to a list of consecutive sub-sequences

Tags: scala

I have this class:

```
case class websiteVisitsWindow(start: Int, end: Int, visitors: Int) {
 def contains(other: websiteVisitsWindow): Boolean = other.start >= this.start && other.end <= this.end
}
```

Given a wide sequence of `websiteVisitsWindow` for example

```
Seq(websiteVisitsWindow(start = 1, end = 3, visitors = 5)
```

I would like to split this `Seq` into equal subsequences as follows:

```
Seq(
websiteVisitsWindow(start = 1, end = 1, visitors = 5), 
websiteVisitsWindow(start = 2, end = 2, visitors = 5), 
websiteVisitsWindow(start = 3, end = 3, visitors = 5)
)
```

`visitors` value is not of importance at this stage. I have a basic solution that solves my problem for non wide websiteVisitsWindow (given a and b sequence generate 3 sets, set 1: intersection of a and b, set2: left join of a and b, set3: right join of b and a)

```
def splitIntoSets(as: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], bs: 
Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]): (Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], 
Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]) = {
(as, bs) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => (Nil, Nil, Nil)
  case (_, Nil) => (Nil, as, Nil)
  case (Nil, _) => (Nil, bs, Nil)

  case _ =>
    if (bs.forall(currentItem => currentItem.start == currentItem.end)
      (
        as.filter(a => bs.exists(b => b.contains(a))),
        as.filter(a => !(bs.exists(b => b.contains(a)))),
        bs.filter(b => !(as.exists(a => a.contains(b))))
      )
    else
    {
      //for each Bs that is a wide websiteVisitsWindow break it down to a sub-sequence of smaller websiteVisitsWindow
      // i,e, websiteVisitsWindow(start = 1, end = 2, visitors = 10) => Seq(websiteVisitsWindow(start = 1, end = 1, visitors = 10), websiteVisitsWindow(start = 2, end = 2, visitors = 10))

      splitIntoSets(as, b +: bs)
    }

}
}
```

I am not sure if this is a right approach but I am currently thinking of something like this (pseudocode):

```
- Find the number of sequences to generate (essentially grabbing start and end values)
- Generate an websiteVisitWindow for each item in range from start value to end value as above such that the start and end values are set as the current value in the range
- Append this websiteVisitWindow to the list of bs
- Iterate over the wide interval, breaking it down until the end condition is met
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with a recursive function, took me a while but I got this to work in the end.

```
def splitIntoSets(visitors: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], schedule: Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]): (Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow], Seq[websiteVisitsWindow]) = {
(visitors, schedule) match {
  case (Nil, Nil) => (Nil, Nil, Nil)
  case (_, Nil) => (Nil, visitors, Nil)
  case (Nil, _) => (Nil, schedule, Nil)

  case _ =>
    if (schedule.forall(currentItem => currentItem.start == currentItem.end)) {

      (
        visitors.filter(visitor => schedule.exists(scheduleWebsiteVisitsWindow => scheduleWebsiteVisitsWindow.contains(visitor))),
        visitors.filter(visitor => !(schedule.exists(scheduleWebsiteVisitsWindow => scheduleWebsiteVisitsWindow.contains(visitor)))),
        schedule.filter(scheduleWebsiteVisitsWindow => !(visitors.exists(visitor => visitor.contains(scheduleWebsiteVisitsWindow))))
      )
    }
    else {

      val (sameStartEndTimes, wideStartEndTimes) = schedule.partition(websiteVisitsWindow => websiteVisitsWindow.start == websiteVisitsWindow.end)

      val startTime = wideStartEndTimes.map(firstValue => firstValue.start).toSeq(0).toInt
      val endTime = wideStartEndTimes.map(firstValue => firstValue.end).toSeq(0).toInt

      val startEndTimeList = (startTime to endTime).toList

      val expandedWideWebsiteVisitsWindow = startEndTimeList.map(
        currentItem => websiteVisitsWindow(start = currentItem, end = currentItem, visitors = 0)
      )

      val remainingWideWebsiteVisitsWindows = wideStartEndTimes.tail

      splitIntoSets(visitors, (sameStartEndTimes ++ expandedWebsiteVisitsWindow ++ remainingWideWebsiteVisitsWindows))
    }

}
}
```